# D7, Views 3 | How do you conditionally rewrite fields?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

In Views, when I rewrite a field and then hide some other fields and use their tokens to compile them into that first one I rewrite, how would I go about doing an operation such as this:

**Example:**

Say I have these fields:

- field_first_name
- field_last_name
- field_old_nickname
- field_new_nickname

Everyone has a first & last name, but:

- Some people have ONLY an old nickname
- Some people have ONLY a new nickname
- Some people have both an old & new nickname

What if I want to rewrite these fields into a format such as **"John (Nobody) Doe?"**

Normally, we would hide all fields but the first name and do this:

**[field_first_name] ([field_new_nickname]) [field_last_name]**

But what if John has a old nickname too and we want to display the old one instead if that's the case?

Get what I'm saying?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: p.s. I'm actually using the "Views PDF" module to generate PDF files. It has most of the same Views options so I'd have to stick with what Views offers in itself. If you guys know how I can do the above, I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the option "exclude from display if empty" for the
   two fields "field_new_nickname" and "field_old_nickname"
2. then rewrite the output field as : [field_first_name]
   ([field_new_nickname] ,[field_old_nickname]) [field_last_name]
3. so the empty field will not show up

Answer (score 0):

A #drupal-support IRC user named "ciss" answered this question for me-- it was much easier than I had thought, which is great. Thank you ciss!:

"Regarding your tokens question: you can use tokens in the empty output of a field. That way you can trigger which tokens should get displayed. Make sure you pick a field for rewriting that can actually be empty (either empty string or "0"). if necessary, add a specific field twice-- Views will *not* check if the rewritten content is empty."